# What is the best way to access /var/www on another computer?

Tags: server, client, upload

If you are making a website on Ubuntu Desktop and you want to move your files to another computer with Ubuntu Server, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried SSH?

Comment: Yes. What other ways are there, and what is the best ssh way?

Comment: Hmm. I've never done it. It should be a short search, though. Samba might also help.

Comment: Have a look at [`vsftp`](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html)

Comment: Can I access /var/www using nautilus and ssh?

Comment: Depends on your needs, you could put your site in Git, and setup some hooks to handle the local -> remote/production. This requires you to learn a new skill, but is very powerful and can handle almost everything you want. But if you want to keep it simple, I would recommend SSH file transfer (SFTP).

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to give a user access to a remote webserver is through FTP (File Transfer Protocol).

You can install [`vsftpd`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vsftpd/) [image: Install vsftpd] on the server and [FileZilla](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/filezilla/) [image: Install filezilla] on the client.

1. Update the `apt` cache: `sudo apt-get update`
2. Install `vsftpd`: `sudo apt-get install vsftpd`
3. Install `filezilla`: `sudo apt-get install filezilla`

Then you can just launch FileZilla on the client and connect to the server.

Of course you'll want to configure the server appropriately: [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd)'s the Community Help Wiki page for `vsftpd` on the Offical Ubuntu Documentation site

Comment: Would I have to change some permissions on /var/www? What is the norm? What permissions should site files have on the /var/www folder?

Comment: @lapisdecor No, but to be able to write to that folder you'll have to give the FTP user write permission to that folder: since that folder is usually owned by `www-data` (`apache2`), the user should be in the `www-data` group in order to modify its content; have a read at [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/VSFTPD-Installation-Setup-on-Ubuntu/step3/Create-the-FTP-users/) to understand correctly how to setup users within `vsftpd`. Once done this correctly, everything works under the same old ownage / permissions rules.

Answer (score 2):

[rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) -- This tool is able to synchronize file and folder recursively in single command line. Optionally, you can :

1. Exclude versioning file system (`--exclude`), such as: .git, .svn
2. Remove remote file or folder which not exists in your desktop (`--delete`)
3. Show progress bar (`--progress`) is usefull when copying huge file

Comment: How does this changes files permissions?

Comment: @lapisdecor , use `--perms` to preserve files permissions

Comment: I don't want to keep them, I want to chown them to root on the server. Can you give-me a full command example?